# Oracle Apex - Migrate to Font Apex

Tags: font-awesome, oracle-apex

We are currently migrating from Font Awesome to Font APEX on Apex 5.1.

We are facing some issues after I changed the Theme to use Font Apex, the icons look in general a bit better and more clear.

But we are facing 2 issues:

1. The stacking option does not seem to work anymore:

When I use this example form the awesome font website it does not show correctly. We used to show the following (circle wiht badges):

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">       
  <i style="color:lightgrey" class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>       
  <i class="fa-stack-1x">2</i>    
</span>
```

Any ideas?

2. We us the Right Side Column Template after the migration the icon to show / hide the right region does not show corretly (see picture).

[image]

Comment: I somehow managed to fix the second issue. In the Theme settings I clicked on "Refresh Theme". Afterwards the icon was displayed correct. The first issue is still unsolved.

Comment: Anyone? Or is it just not possible to stack, Font Apex Icons at all, I guess I have to go back to good old Font Awesome then.

Answer (score -1):

The Icon-Stack Option works with just one span element containing the classes of the two icons:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-apex fam-50-percent"></span>
```

You might want to adjust the css of the upper (small) icon for its position.

For Reference refer to https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:4000:::NO::: there you can try out the icon-options.

Happy apexing

Comment: It would be better to include some examples in the answer rather than just provide a link.

Comment: Yea i formatted the example wrong so it didnt show up

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for I'm looking for a custom stack option like e.g. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#masking or http://blog.fontawesome.io/2014/05/19/stacking-text-and-icons/ . That's so far not possible with Font Apex